# Homotopy equivalence of C-modules

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

A topological leftmodule $_CX$ is a topological functor $C \to Top$ for a Category $C$. A morphism $_CX \to _CY$ of leftmodules is a natural transformation of functors.

Now such a morphism is called an equivalence if it is a strong homotopy equivalence in the category of $C$-Modules.

But how is a strong homotopy equivalence in the category of C-Modules defined?